# Rails 4 - saving images in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Hello dear Programmers,

I'm trying to develop a web application with the ebook "Praxiswissen - Ruby on Rails". My problem is that I want to save Images through a form to my project directory. The database just saves the name of the pictures with the saving time:

```
def unique_and_proper_filename(filename)
    Time.now.to_i.to_s + '_' + File.basename(filename)
end
```

My problem is that my pictures dont get saved after submitting my form. I dont get some exceptions, thats why I dont know where my issue is.

Controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  require 'will_paginate'

  def new
     @post = Post.new
  end

  # information about saving the picture
  def create
     @post = Post.new(params[:post].permit(:title, :description, :date, :image_file, :thumbnail_file))

     # Form isn't correctly filled message
     if !@post.valid?
        flash.now[:notice] = "Bitte f&uuml;llen Sie alle Felder aus und &uuml;berpr&uuml;fen Sie Ihre Angaben."
        render(:action => :new)

     # Files weren't saved message
     elsif !@post.save_files
        flash.now[:notice] = "Es trat ein Fehler beim Hochladen der Dateien auf."
        render(:action => :new)

     # Files saved correctly message
     else
        @post.save
        flash[:notice] = "Dateien wurden hochgeladen und die Daten wurden gespeichert."
        redirect_to(:action => :list)
     end
  end

  # list action for listing my pictures
  def list
    @posts = Post.paginate(:page => params[:page], :order => "date DESC", :per_page => 15)
    @post_pages = Post.paginate(:page => params[:page], :order => "date DESC", :per_page => 15)
  end

end
```

HTML Form:

```
<h2>Neues Foto anlegen</h2>
<%= form_tag({:action => :create}, :multipart => true) %>
<h3>Bilddaten</h3>
<p>
    Titel<br/>
    <%= text_field(:post, :title) %>
</p>
<p>
    Beschreibungen<br/>
    <%= text_field(:post, :description) %>
</p>    
<p>
    Datum und Uhrzeit<br/>  
    <%= datetime_select(:post, :date, :order => [:day, :month, :year, :hour]) %>
</p>
<p>
    <h3>Datei-Upload</h3>   
    <p>
        Bilddatei:<br/>
        <%= file_field(:post, :image_file) %>
    </p>    
    <p>
        Thumbnail:<br/>
        <%= file_field(:post, :thumbnail_file) %>
    </p>
    <%= submit_tag("Speichern") %>
</p>
</form>
```

Model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates_presence_of(:title, :description, :date, :image, :thumbnail)
  I18n.enforce_available_locales = false

  def image_file= (fileobj)
    if fileobj.size > 0
      @image_file = fileobj
      self.image = unique_and_proper_filename(fileobj.original_filename)
    end
  end

  def thumbnail_file= (fileobj)
    if fileobj.size > 0
      @thumbnail_file = fileobj
      self.thumbnail = unique_and_proper_filename(fileobj.original_filename)
    end
  end 

  def save_files

    # Bilddatei save
    if !save_uploaded_file(@image_file, IMAGE_DIR, self.image)
      return false
    end

    # Thumbnail save
    if !save_uploaded_file(@thumbnail_file, THUMBNAIL_DIR, self.thumbnail)
      return false
    end

  end

  private 
  def unique_and_proper_filename(filename)
    Time.now.to_i.to_s + "_" + File.basename(filename)
  end

  private 
  def save_uploaded_file(fileobj, filepath, filename)

    # Complete Path
    complete_path = Rails.root + "/public/" + filepath

    # if neccessary, create directory
    FileUtils.mkdir_p(complete_path) unless File.exists?(complete_path)

    # save data
    begin
      f = File.open(complete_path + "/" + filename, "wb")
      f.write(fileobj.read)
    rescue 
      return false
    ensure
      f.close unless f.nil?
    end

  end

end
```

I'm only getting the message that there went something wrong with saving the files when i fill the form correctly but it should return a message that says that my file were saved.

I'm sorry for that massive length of my question but I really dont know where my issue is... If there's a need for more information or code, I will add it as fast as I can.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Your log file (or server output) will show you the parameters that came to the form, as well as what went wrong and where it happened.  That's always your first place to start when diagnosing a problem like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm lucky to tell that I found my issue. My `save_files` method in my `Post` model doesn't returned `true`..

I post this answer because maybe someone could use this question as an answer for his own problem. Here's where I added my `return true` :

```
def save_files

    # Bilddatei save
    if !save_uploaded_file(@image_file, IMAGE_DIR, self.image)
      return false
    end

    # Thumbnail save
    if !save_uploaded_file(@thumbnail_file, THUMBNAIL_DIR, self.thumbnail)
      return false
    end

    return true   # <--------- Need to be added!

end
```

Answer (score 19):

### **Update 17/02/22:**

Paperclip has since been deprecated, it is recommended you use Rails' own [Active Storage](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html).

### **Original Answer:**

I'm sorry but I'll only be able to recommend what we use:

---

**Paperclip**

I appreciate you're using a tutorial, but I'd highly recommend using the [Paperclip gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) for this

This handles ALL the heavy lifting for you:

```
#GemFile
gem "paperclip", "~> 4.1.1"
```

---

**Model**

```
#app/models/post.rb
Class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :image
end

#migration
add_attachment :posts, :image
```

---

**Controller**

```
#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
def new
    @post = Post.new
end

def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
end

private

def post_params
     params.require(:post).permit(:image, :other, :params)
end
```

---

**View**

```
#app/views/posts/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Paperclip is great, and i'd also recommend it as the way to go when making a proper app, but when learning there's a lot to be said for knowing how to do something yourself rather than just handing it over to a magical gem to do it.  I actually think that "magic" is Rails' biggest problem for people learning how to use it.

Comment: Yes, I'm using a tutorial.. Thank you for the recommendation! Of course i upvote your answer but I would prefer to follow my tutorial and find the problem in my existing code. If there will be no more answers that help me with my code I will accept your answer and give "paperclip" a try. Thank you!

Comment: Of course - I just wanted to highlight the options for you :)

Comment: This answer is good for 2014 but now since rails 5.2, the built-in gem called active storage handles everything previously done by paperclip, dragonfly, carrierwave etc.

Answer (score -2):

Try to add enctype= multipart/formdata in your form tag if you are using form to post your data

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue