# How to save image for blog post in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system, blogs, refinerycms

I'm building a blog in Rails and want to add images to posts.

I'm basically writing the HTML into a text area and save it into the database. Then I print the post content with `@post.content` on my show page.

Normally, you can use `<%= image_tag 'mypic.jpg %>` to render the dynamic image url, but since it gets saved as a string in the database, this doesn't work in this case.

**How do I save my image tag in the database?**

How do cms or blog engines and editors like [CKeditor](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor) deal with this problem?

Comment: last post on this page is your answer:

[Rails 4 - saving images in database][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22247582/rails-4-saving-images-in-database

Answer (score 1):

By default rails will escape the HTML tags in a string. To print the post content string in HTML format, you can use the `raw()` method. You can also use `html_safe`. Raw is usually preferred because it won't raise an exception if the value passed to it is nil.

`<%= raw @post.content %>` or `<%= @post.content.html_safe %>`

Keep in mind, you should only use these methods on strings that you know are safe from cross-site scripting XXS. If your site is accepting user input, this could be a security vulnerability.

CKEditor works with file uploading gems like Carrierwave or Dragonfly. Implementing CKEditor with img uploads requires a new database table, which will save images on your server when uploaded through the text editor. The path to the image is saved within the Post string in an `<img>` tag. CKEditor also generates a set of routes to handle paths for uploaded images.

Comment: It's not working because now `<%= image_tag "mypic.jpg"%> gets printed instead of showing the image

Comment: Right, the embedded ruby code will be printed when it's in a string, even if using html_safe or raw. You will have to use a standard html img tag for your picture to show up. Building this from scratch would require another model for your images, then you would have to map their paths to each img tag in the Post content. Or you can use the CKEditor gem to do this for you.